# What does 'DST not supported' mean?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Another follow-up to my question [Is it normal for a SATA drive to show 0MB size in BIOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/276664/is-it-normal-for-a-sata-drive-to-show-0mb-size-in-bios)

What does 'DST not supported' mean? Is this good, or bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think DST is Drive Self Test.  Odd that it would be 'not supported' on a late model SATA drive.

Comment: The idea of enforcing the RMA grows on me ...